# Javascript: value not shows correctly for float

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code in angular that get data from google finance. However, it can get data for **vo** and **avvo** correctly if M or K exists which represent millions and thousands. If without it, it can not shows the value properly.

How can I handle both cases to take data correctly?

example data as below. The first one has float data and second one has M which I think is string. I can shows correctly for string but float is incorrect. It will shows vo as N/A and avvo as 2.000. I want to shows the exact value in the data

```
// [
{
"id": "549805688244420"
,"t" : "AZG"
,"vo" : "0.00"
,"avvo" : "2,087.00"

}
]
```

and

```
// [
{
"id": "381558643124633"
,"t" : "U11"
,"vo" : "1.34M"
,"avvo" : "2.47M"

}
]
```

Below is my code:

```
angular.module('myapp.factories').factory('$stockDataFactory',
  ['$q', '$filter', '$webServicesFactory',
    function ($q, $filter, $webServicesFactory) {
      return {
        getStockDetails: function (stock) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $webServicesFactory.getNotParsed(
            "https://www.google.com/finance/info",
            {},
            {
              infotype: "infoquoteall",
              q: stock.market+":"+stock.symbol
            }
          ).then(
            function success(response) {
              response = JSON.parse("["+response.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ' ').split('[').splice(1,1)[0]);
              stock = response[0];
        var formatedData = {
                  volume: stock.vo,
                  averageDailyVolume: stock.avvo
           };
```

html:

```
  <div class="row row-center">
    <div class="col boldText">Volume: </div>
    <div class="col col-21">{{stock.volume || 'N/A'}}</div>
    <div class="col boldText">Avg. Vol: </div>
    <div class="col col-21">{{(stock.averageDailyVolume | shrinkNumber: 2) || 'N/A'}}</div>
  </div>
```

shrinkNumber in js

```
angular.module('chaishen.factories').filter("shrinkNumber", function($filter) {
  return function(number, fractionSize) {

    if(number === null) return null;
    if(number === 0) return "0.000";

    // default number of decimals for values >1000 or <-1000 if not set in view
    if(!fractionSize || fractionSize < 0)
      fractionSize = 1;

    var abs = Math.abs(number);
    var rounder = Math.pow(10,fractionSize);
    var isNegative = number < 0;
    var key = '';
    var powers = [
      {key: "Q", value: Math.pow(10,15)},
      {key: "T", value: Math.pow(10,12)},
      {key: "B", value: Math.pow(10,9)},
      {key: "M", value: Math.pow(10,6)},
      {key: "K", value: 1000}
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < powers.length; i++) {

      var reduced = abs / powers[i].value;

      //reduced = Math.round(reduced * rounder) / rounder;
      reduced = Math.round(abs * rounder) / rounder;

      if(reduced >= 1){
        abs = reduced;
        key = powers[i].key;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(number >= 1000) {
      //return abs + key;
      return abs;
    }
    else if(number <= -1000) {
      //return '-' + abs + key;
      return '-' + abs;
    }
    else {
      //return $filter('number')(((isNegative ? '-' : '') + abs + key), 3);
      return $filter('number')(((isNegative ? '-' : '') + abs), 3);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Knowledge-Base/Floating-point-numbers-are-surprisingly-strange/ta-p/29049

Comment: @OneNeptune how is it related to my question?

Comment: declared as they are, your floats are just strings. But what do you mean by "float is incorrect"? how are they displayed? what is your correct way to have them? is it on a html page? where?

Comment: @Kaddath edit with html added. It shows 0 as N/A and 2,870.00 as 2.00. I put N/A in html as sometimes, the data is '-' and it will display as N/A. Thanks

Comment: @bkcollection you're still trying to do math operations on strings. Not going to work out for you. Here are three different ways to coerce: `Number(stock.avvo); +stock.avvo; parseInt(stock.avvo, 10)`.

Comment: `"vo" : "1.34M"` needs to be `"vo" : 1.34M` I would guess. Otherwise yeah it's trying to do maths on a string (it might look like a float, but it isn't as far as JS is concerned, unless you parse it as one first, or ditch the quotes in the JSON)

Comment: @ADyson thanks. But I have no control of the data. It comes with `"vo" : "1.34M"` in json. How shall I do in my js script?

Comment: @bkcollection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat . But if you have any influence with the creator of the data you also should raise a bug to tell them they're outputting the JSON incorrectly.